# how to rightAlign numeric edited values in grails tables

Tags: grails

I have a table defined in a gsp-file. The table has a column with numeric edited numbers. I want to rightAlign them, so that the decimalPoints are all in the same position one under the corresponding one in the preceeding line.

peter

Comment: Put your relevant code here as well if you can.

Comment: Simplest way would be to add `style="text-align: right;"` on your `td`, better to create a `class` to contain that and assign the class name to the `td`.

Comment: How many decimal places would you have in max? to the 10ths or to the 100ths?

Comment: style="text-align: right;" works fine

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Try it [<kbd>**here**</kbd>](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5662979341156352).

```
[
    '1.0', 
    '115.00', 
    '0.0', 
    '100.0', 
    '24.9', 
    '4.09', 
    '54.09', 
    '13452.098', 
    '134520.098', 
    '198.0', 
    '0.98'
].each { 
    def (whole, fraction) = it.tokenize(/./)
    println ( [ whole.padLeft(6), fraction ].join(/./) ) 
}

//Output
     1.0
   115.00
     0.0
   100.0
    24.9
     4.09
    54.09
 13452.098
134520.098
   198.0
     0.98
```

**Assumption:**

- All Decimal numbers
- Max 6 digit whole number

Comment: that's exactly what I needed for printing the stuff displayed on screen

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `padLeft` method as dmahapatro suggested if you are using a fixed-width font, however, if you are not, you are going to have to use some CSS to format it correctly. I suggest putting everything to the right of the decimal place (including the decimal) in a span, giving it a fixed width and aligning it to the left. Check out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fvp3obxr/. You might need to adjust the width depending on how many decimal places you have.